# Power BI Dax Year over Year Calculation

Tags: datetime, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to figure out the DAX equation for Prior Year Sales and not getting any luck.

I have Date Table and a Sales Table with a Date Slicer

> Slicer 10/15/2023   10/21/2023
>
> | Day of the Week | Total Sales | Total Sales Prior Year |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Sunday | 100,500 |  |
> | Monday | 150,500 |  |
> | Tuesday | 204,000 |  |
> | etc. | etc. |  |
> | Total | 750,000 |  |

For some reason all I am getting is the total

I tired PRIORYEAR with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update your question to include your DAX expression for what you have tried or are using.

Comment: I'd check DAXPatterns dot com for that. 
Basically something like 
CALCULATE ( [total sales], DATEADD(year,-1,DimDate[Date]))

(yeah, I can't remember the sequence of arguments for DATEADD... it's so awesome that they're different in SQL Server, Excel, and PowerBI.)